Bootstrap-select not accessible to screen readers. Not behaving like standard select dropdowns in any browser. Menu items not being read in Firefox
Try below code in a browser with NVDA.
The plain HTML original select dropdown works as expected with NVDA screenreader reading out the individual menu items when you go up or down with cursor keys or TAB key and telling you how many items is in list and where you currently are in list.
The various bootstrap-select versions of this do not work at all - screenreader reads BLANK, BLANK, BLANK all the way through menu and does not tell you where you are or how long the list is.
I am using Bootstrap-select v1.13.18
TAB INTO the searchable bootstrap-select widget
NVDA SPEAKS: nothing selected - combo box - nothing selected - collapsed - opens list
SPACE KEY - does nothing
NVDA SPEAKS: space
DOWN ARROW - opens menu
NVDA SPEAKS: search combobox - collapsed - has autocomplete - editable - blank
UP/DOWN ARROWS
NVDA SPEAKS: blank - blank - blank - blank

TAB INTO the normal bootstrap-select widget
NVDA SPEAKS: nothing selected - combo box - nothing selected - collapsed - opens list
SPACE KEY - does nothing
NVDA SPEAKS: space
DOWN ARROW - opens menu
NVDA SPEAKS: expanded
UP/DOWN ARROWS
NVDA SPEAKS: <no speech at all - does not read any menu item>

TAB INTO the normal select widget
NVDA SPEAKS: combo box - collapsed
SPACE KEY - opens menu
NVDA SPEAKS: space - combo box - expanded - list - list item 1 of 13
UP/DOWN ARROW - < menu item text >
NVDA SPEAKS: < next/previous menu item text >
UP/DOWN ARROWS
NVDA SPEAKS: < menu item text > < position > of 13

Has this never been tested with screen-readers to ensure compliance or even basic functionality or is there something missing in the code here I need to add?
INSTRUCTIONS FOR SNIPPET TEST HERE
NVDA instructions to test problem and skip all the other stuff on page in screen reader

Expand the widget to full screen
Hit key combo INSERT-F7 to open the NVDA "Elements List"
Go to Headings
Click Test ARIA plain dropdown
Click "Move To" button - this closes the NVDA window and put reader on the main heading on test
Use TAB key and ARROW keys to navigate the top two Bootstrap widgets - notice reader never read out the list item names
Use SPACE key and ARROW keys to navigate standard HTML dropdown - notice reader reads out the items in list

NOTE: on real system it also announces BLANK all over the place for some reason but not in example here.


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rVCTTkUfGk7/0pbek5mMa1upzvWbrUbOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-aJ21OjlMXNL5UyIl/XNwTMqvzeRMZH2w8c5cRVpzpU8Y5bApTppSuUkhZXN0VxHd" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<h3>Test ARIA plain dropdown</h3>

<h4>bootstrap-select version - with search</h4>

<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search-style="contains" data-live-search-normalize="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search" data-live-search="true">
  <option value="49033">  Life Sciences&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49041"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Agricultural and Biological Sciences&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49042"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Biochemistry, Genetics and Molecular Biology&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49043"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Immunology and Microbiology&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49034">  Health Sciences&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49044"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Medicine&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49045"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Nursing&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49046"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Veterinary&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49040">  Physical Sciences&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49047"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Chemical Engineering&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49048"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Computer Science&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49049"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Earth and Planetary&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
</select>

<h4>bootstrap-select version - without search</h4>

<select class="selectpicker">
  <option value="49033">  Life Sciences&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49041"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Agricultural and Biological Sciences&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49042"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Biochemistry, Genetics and Molecular Biology&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49043"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Immunology and Microbiology&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49034">  Health Sciences&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49044"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Medicine&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49045"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Nursing&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49046"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Veterinary&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49040">  Physical Sciences&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49047"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Chemical Engineering&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49048"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Computer Science&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49049"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Earth and Planetary&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
</select>

<h4>Plain HTML version</h4>

<select >
  <option></option><option value="49033">  Life Sciences&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49041"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Agricultural and Biological Sciences&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49042"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Biochemistry, Genetics and Molecular Biology&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49043"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Immunology and Microbiology&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49034">  Health Sciences&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49044"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Medicine&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49045"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Nursing&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49046"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Veterinary&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49040">  Physical Sciences&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49047"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Chemical Engineering&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49048"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Computer Science&nbsp;&nbsp;</option><option value="49049"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Earth and Planetary&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
</select>




Can you post a link to a test page please ? It will be easier for everyone to test and then to help. Thank you.

Tried adding code snippet here but its not displaying the bootstrap-select properly when run for some reason.

You can still post a link to a test page.

I would love to, but I am having trouble finding some suitable webhost - is there some standard one people here use for this sort of thing? Or did you mean just attach the HTML test file to this question?

I only mean a link to a page where anyone can test and reproduce the problem, nothing more. The link can point anywhere you want, a real page on your own site, or one on all those code snippet sharing sites. It doesn't matter much. Stackoverflow rules don't allow making recommandations for a particular site of that kind. Normally you should even be able to embed directly that kind of thing so that a "run" button appears directly below your code. I can't tell you why it doesn't work here.

Oh, that run button I was talking about has appeared, so it should be fine now. I have quickly tried it and I can say that it mostly works with Jaws.

No the "Run Code" functionality does not work with this Bootstrap code properly as I said previously - it just displays the first two Bootstrap examples as a plain HTML dropdown with a button to right and input box below - they are not supposed to look like that - it means the actual bootstrap javascript is not running which turns them into the fancy bootstrap select/search type inputs.

OK found the problem with the snippet - the bootstrap running now in example here so first two dropdowns look like they should.

Added instructions to test screen reader using snippet here.

I just tried again and all three lists work fine for me with latest Jaws or NVDA on Chrome. I correctly get the select item when pressing up/down arrow. However,  with the first and the second list, Tab goes through each item when the list is expanded while it shouldn't, and Shift+Tab doesn't allow to go backward. This is quite important. The third list doesn't tell the number of the selected item out of 13, but it's a minor thing.

Oh I see now they seem to work in Chrome alright... I was testing in Firefox - does not work at all in latest Firefox!
